Teamwork Cloud 2021 Install errors
I have been trying to install everything needed for Teamwork Cloud 2021X using these instructions https://docs.nomagic.com/display/TWCloud2021x/Installation+on+Linux+using+scripts
When I get to executing install_twc2021xRefresh1_centos7.sh  I get the following output
Creating temporary directory for install anywhereIMPORTANT:When prompted for user to run service, use twcloudWhen prompted for Java Home location, use Java 11 location, e.g., /opt/local/java/jdk-11.0.9.1+1-Press any key to continue ...: Binary file /data/install/custom matchesBinary file /data/install/custom matchesBinary file /data/install/custom matchesgzip: /data/install/_tmp/install.dir.43574/Linux/resource/vm.tar.Z: not in gzip format./twcloud_2021x_installer_linux64.bin: line 775: uncompress: command not foundgzip: /data/install/_tmp/install.dir.43574/Linux/resource/vm.tar.Z: not in gzip formatBinary file /data/install/custom matches Binary file /data/install/custom matcheschown: cannot access '/opt/local/TeamworkCloud/': No such file or directorysed: can't read /opt/local/TeamworkCloud/configuration/application.conf: No such file or directorysed: can't read /opt/local/TeamworkCloud/AuthServer/config/authserver.properties: No such file or directory```

Here is the “custom” file that is created after failure:
en_prepareInstall=Preparing to install
en_checksumPassed=MD5 checksum verification for downloaded JVM passed
en_noEnoughSpace=WARNING: $INSTBASE does not have enough disk space! Attempting to use $HOME for install base and tmp dir.
en_jreUnzipFailed=The included VM could not be uncompressed (GZIP/UNCOMPRESS).
en_reDownload=Please try to download the installer again and make sure that you download using 'binary' mode. Please do not attempt to install this currently downloaded copy.
en_noPermission=The temporary install directory: $INSTBASE does not exist or you do not have permission to write to it.
en_downloadLoc2=Download location=$jreDownloadFileName_1
en_downloadLoc1=Download location=$jreDownloadFileName
en_iatempdirNotPresent=You have used the IATEMPDIR to set the install base and tmp dir for this installation. However, the directory $INSTBASE does not exist or is not a directory. Please choose a valid directory.
en_extractRes=Extracting the installation resources from the installer archive...
en_tmpCleanup=WARNING! This installation has been interrupted. The installation process will now terminate and the temporary files it is using will be deleted from $ZIPLOC.
en_invalidUnzip=Invalid unzip command found
en_extractJRE=Extracting the JRE from the installer archive...
en_spaceUndetermined=WARNING! The amount of $INSTBASE disk space required and/or available could not be determined. The installation will attempted anyway.
en_vmDownloadError=Error in downloading the VM. Installer exiting...
en_downloadedVM1=Downloaded VM Pack using URL=$jvmSpecBuildWithoutVMNotFoundDownloadUrl
en_downloadedVM2=Downloaded VM Pack using URL=$jvmSpecBuildWithoutVmDirectDownloadUrl
en_needMoreSpace=WARNING! The amount of $INSTBASE disk space required to perform this installation is greater than what is available. Please free up at least $free_up kilobytes in $INSTBASE and attempt this installation again.
en_default=default
en_jreUntarFailed=The included VM could not be unarchived (TAR).
en_launch=Launching installer...
en_installInvalidUnzip=InstallAnywhere could not find a supported unzip program on the system, this should not have any impact on the installation process.
en_checksumFailed=Error!! MD5 checksum verification for downloaded JVM failed. Installer exiting...
en_configure=Configuring the installer for this system's environment...
en_jreExtractFailed=The included VM could not be extracted.
en_unpackJRE=Unpacking the JRE...
en_defaultCase=d

It seems as though these error messages are all being generated by default regardless of changes I make
This occurs even though I have enough space and full permissions for $INSTBASE - /opt/local and $IATEMPDIR - /tmp)  Although, the instructions do not refer to needing to set these; I tried it to troubleshoot and get the same errors.
*I did have to modify twcloud_2021x_installer_linux64.bin to allow Rocky as the OS (It checks for Cent-OS, which Rocky is meant to be binary compatible with)
Added a check for the presence of /etc/rocky-release file alongside the existing check for /etc/centos-release. If either file exists, it assigns the contents to DISTRO_NAME.
